# BigQuery dataset maintenance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It looks like over the period we have different versions of Tables/Views in the BigQuery data set. It's confusing at time to pick which one to use.

What is the best way  to cleanup unnecessary/unused tables apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an export sink from the bq access logs and then identify the unused tables based on that
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/